# JSON serialize std::list and std::map using cpprestsdk

Tags: json, stl, cpprest-sdk

I am using cpprestsdk to write a server application in C++ that uses REST services. In my application, I have to serialize a class that contains std::list and std::map objects to JSON.

Is there any example on serialize STL classes using cpprestsdk(https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize `std::list` and `std::map` as JSON arrays. One example for `std::map` is

```
void mapToJson()
{
    web::json::value result = web::json::value::array();
    std::map<int, utility::string_t> m;

    int i = 0;
    for each (std::pair<int, utility::string_t> p in m)
    {
        web::json::value obj = web::json::value::object();

        obj[U("integer")] = web::json::value(p.first);
        obj[U("string")] = web::json::value(p.second);

        result[i++] = obj;
    }
}
```